# Generating Print .txt file directly using DocPrintJob for DotMatrix Printer

Tags: java, printing, dot-matrix

I am printing a .txt file using DocPrintJob. This works fine.
The file will be printed from a **Dot Matrix Printer**. Now, the issue which I am facing is -:

- As per my requirement, the paper needs to set back automatically to
  perforated position after printing one record.
- But while printing directly from the application, the paper is not automatically setting back to perforated position.
- But while giving print of file manually by opening in notepad, printing happens properly with automatic paper adjustment i.e. the paper sets back to the perforated position for next printing

I tried using line feeds and carriage returns at the end of each page. But it didn't work out.
Is there any way out to set the adjustment of printer through code?
Here is my sample code -:

```
private static void print(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException, PrintException {
     FileInputStream textStream;
     textStream = new FileInputStream(fileName);
     DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE;
     Doc mydoc = new SimpleDoc(textStream, flavor, null);   
      // Set the printer Name
     PrintService service = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
     PrintServiceAttributeSet printServiceAttributeSet = new HashPrintServiceAttributeSet();
     printServiceAttributeSet.add(new PrinterName(service.getName(), null));
     // Set the paper size and orientation
     PrintRequestAttributeSet printRequestAttributeSet = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
     printRequestAttributeSet.add(new MediaPrintableArea(0, 0, 4, 9, MediaPrintableArea.INCH));
     printRequestAttributeSet.add(OrientationRequested.LANDSCAPE);
     InputStream is = null;
     try {
          PrintRequestAttributeSet  pras = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
            pras.add(new Copies(1));
         DocPrintJob job = service.createPrintJob();
         PrintJobWatcher pjw = new PrintJobWatcher(job);
         job.print(mydoc, printRequestAttributeSet);
         pjw.waitForDone();
     }catch(Exception e){
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
     finally{
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }

 }
```